# EJB 3.1 security roles if not specified

Tags: ejb-3.1

I have a EJB 3.1 bean that uses some roles. But my current environment supporst just users, without roles.

EJB 3.1 Core specification, chapter 17.4.2 says that if the Deployer does not assign the logical security roles defined by the application to groups in the operational environment, it must be assumed that a logical role maps to a principal or principal group of the same name. This means that if there are no roles in the environment, the role names given in the bean are assumed to be "Users". Thus, the bean will work as expected without any issue. You can define users in your environment with names that match all the role names given in the bean.

So, my bean will work jsut fine in current env and I can use isCallerInRole("user1") in bean's business method to check user1 defined in system?